# Maximum call stack size exceeded JS

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to understand the concept of recursion and wanted to use it in my code (the getUniqueInt function):

```js
var getRandomInt = function (min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};

var getChosenNumbers = function (min, max) {
  var chosenNumbers = [];
  for (var k = min; k <= max; k++) {
    chosenNumbers.push(k);
  }
  return chosenNumbers;
};

var arrayOfNumbers = getChosenNumbers(1, 8);

var getUniqueInt = function (min, max) {
  var uniqueNumber;
  var randomNumber = getRandomInt(min, max);
  if (arrayOfNumbers.indexOf(randomNumber) !== -1) {
    uniqueNumber = randomNumber;
    arrayOfNumbers.splice(arrayOfNumbers.indexOf(uniqueNumber), 1);
  } else {
    uniqueNumber = getUniqueInt(min, max);
  }
  return uniqueNumber;
};
```

But I end up getting this:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

What am I doing wrong? And does my code (I mean the recursion part) make any sense or it's totally wrong?

Comment: Your snippet does not result in the error you describe. `Uncaught ReferenceError: ADS_COUNT is not defined` and plugging in a number there doesn't look to result in a problem either. Can you edit it so that when pressing "Run code snippet", the result displayed is "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded", so we can see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what I am basically trying to do here is to get a range of numbers (array of numbers) and then choose one of these numbers randomly without repeating the already chosen ones;

Your `getRandomInt` function is a good start -

```
const getRandomInt = (min = 0, max = 0) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
```

Let's make a function to make a range of numbers -

```
const makeRange = (min = 0, max = 0) =>
  min > max
    ? []
    : [ min, ...makeRange(min + 1, max) ]
```

We don't have to loop to find the next random value. We can `swap` elements in an array to efficiently create a random sequence. This technique is known as [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) -

```
const getUniqueRandom = (min = 0, max = 0) =>
{ const r = makeRange(min, max)

  const next = (i = 0) =>
  { if (i >= r.length) return undefined
    swap(r, i, getRandomInt(i, r.length))
    return r[i]
  }

  let i = 0
  const rand = () =>
    next(i++)

  return rand
}
```

Finally we need to write the `swap` function -

```
const swap = (a = [], i = 0, j = 0) =>
  [a[j], a[i]] = [a[i], a[j]]
```

Now here's how it works -

```
const rand = getUniqueRandom(3,7)

console.log(rand()) // 4
console.log(rand()) // 7
```

Keep calling it to get the rest of the values. It returns `undefined` when there is no possible unique to output -

```
console.log(rand()) // 3
console.log(rand()) // 6
console.log(rand()) // 5
console.log(rand()) // undefined
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the output in your own browser. Press **Run** many times to see the randomised outputs -

```js
const getRandomInt = (min = 0, max = 0) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min

const makeRange = (min = 0, max = 0) =>
  min > max
    ? []
    : [ min, ...makeRange(min + 1, max) ]
    
const swap = (a = [], i = 0, j = 0) =>
  [a[j], a[i]] = [a[i], a[j]]

const getUniqueRandom = (min, max) =>
{ const r = makeRange(min, max)
  
  const next = (i = 0) =>
  { if (i >= r.length)
      return undefined
    swap(r, i, getRandomInt(i, r.length))
    return r[i]
  }
  
  let i = 0
  const rand = () =>
    next(i++)
  
  return rand
}
      
const rand = getUniqueRandom(3,7)

console.log(rand()) // 4
console.log(rand()) // 7
console.log(rand()) // 3
console.log(rand()) // 6
console.log(rand()) // 5
console.log(rand()) // undefined
```

---

**generators**

What `rand` demonstrates above is some sort of *generator*. Modern JavaScript has native support for [Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) allowing us to write this program in a convenient way. You may have heard them called [coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) in other languages.

Here's a very simple generator we can use for `makeRange`.  Note the use of `yield` instead of `return` -

```
const makeRange = function* (min = 0, max = 0)
{ while (min <= max)
    yield min++
}
```

And here's a rewrite of `getUniqueRandom`. We can gather all the values from `makeRange(...)` by using `Array.from` -

```
const getUniqueRandom = function* (min, max)
{ const r =
    Array.from(makeRange(min, max))

  for (let i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
  { swap(r, i, getRandomInt(i, r.length))
    yield r[i]
  }
}
```

To get the unique randoms out one-by-one -

```
const rand = getUniqueRandom(3,7)

console.log(rand.next()) // { value: 7, done: false }
console.log(rand.next()) // { value: 3, done: false }
```

Just as before, keep calling to get the next unique randoms. We see `value: undefined` and `done: true` when there are no more results -

```
console.log(rand.next()) // { value: 6, done: false }
console.log(rand.next()) // { value: 5, done: false }
console.log(rand.next()) // { value: 4, done: false }
console.log(rand.next()) // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Just like we did with `makeRange`, if we want all of the results right away, we can simply use `Array.from` -

```
console.log(Array.from(getUniqueRandom(3, 7)))
// [ 6, 3, 4, 5, 7 ]
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the output in your own browser. Press **Run** many times to see the randomised outputs -

```js
const getRandomInt = (min = 0, max = 0) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min

const swap = (a = [], i = 0, j = 0) =>
  [a[j], a[i]] = [a[i], a[j]]
      
const makeRange = function* (min = 0, max = 0)
{ while (min <= max)
    yield min++
}

const getUniqueRandom = function* (min, max)
{ const r =
    Array.from(makeRange(min, max))

  for (let i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
  { swap(r, i, getRandomInt(i, r.length))
    yield r[i]
  }
}

const rand = getUniqueRandom(3,7)

console.log(rand.next()) // { value: 7, done: false }
console.log(rand.next()) // { value: 3, done: false }
console.log(rand.next()) // { value: 6, done: false }
console.log(rand.next()) // { value: 5, done: false }
console.log(rand.next()) // { value: 4, done: false }
console.log(rand.next()) // { value: undefined, done: true }

console.log(Array.from(getUniqueRandom(3, 7)))
// [ 6, 3, 4, 5, 7 ]
```

Comment: You’re very welcome. Let me know if you need any help using this answer :)

Comment: sorry, could you please elaborate on swap a bit? Is it a function? I'm a bit confused by the "a = [], i = 0, j = 0" line

Comment: No apologies! Yes, `swap` is a function. We could write `const swap = (a, i, j) => ...` but I wrote it with [default arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), `a = [], i = 0, j = 0`. This is a habit I picked up over time as it's helpful in communicating the parameter's _type_ to the reader; and it means can preserve sensible output if you forgot to supply arguments, etc. We can write other functions like this too, such as `const makeRange = (min = 0, max = 0) => ...` - I edited the post to use this style consistently.

Comment: @MikeL. JavaScript has support for [coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) implemented as [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) in JavaScript. I added a section about this in the updated answer ^^

Comment: What makes you choose `Array.from(foo)` over `[...foo]`?  I haven't figured out the correct balance for myself between the more explicit call and the one with less visual noise.  Do you have a rule?

Comment: I do like Fischer-Yates as a generator.  I've had need for that before and didn't think of it.

Comment: Scott, Unless I'm concating/appending/prepending arrays, I choose `Array.from` most of the time because it is a normal function and not a syntactic sugar. It also supports mapping in the second argument, which is often used when consuming an iterator. This is also my first time using Fisher-Yates in a generator and I think its use-cases are widespread...

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense, sorry, and here's why

- set min=0, max=10
- `getRandomInt` returns random int within 0-10
- `getChosenNumbers` returns array of int FROM 0-10, meaning [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
- `arrayOfNumbers` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` now

**`getUniqueInt` simply cannot get uniq, because all possible random values of `getRandomInt` are already within `getChosenNumbers`**

Thats why

```
 else {
    uniqueNumber = getUniqueInt(min, max);
  }
```

gets called infinite times, because

```
arrayOfNumbers.indexOf(randomNumber) !== -1
```

is never true

Comment: no problem, thank you for your answer! But what I am basically trying to do here is to get a range of numbers (array of numbers) and then choose one of these numbers randomly without repeating the already chosen ones; how can I improve my code and is there any way I can use recursion (this is basically just for myself)?