# js face Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, webkit

I have studied some [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765103/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-js), but I'm still stock on some point

- website's console output (**Maximum call stack size exceeded**)

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> at access (code.jquery.com_jquery-3.7.0.js:3871:22)
> at jQuery.fn.init.attr (code.jquery.com_jquery-3.7.0.js:7862:10)
> at containsPmdClassPrefix (pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:181:15)
> at processNode (pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:149:8)
> at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:173:6
> at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:139:5
> at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:174:7
> at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:174:7
> at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:174:7
> at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:174:7

After researching, I guessed that it keep executing(into the loop)
Therefore, I tried to put console.log to see which part is looping

1. I put `console.log("create_certain_ipc_log_table how many times??")`, know that create_certain_ipc_log_table() is executed once when the web page is just refreshed
2. `console.log("DATA for table 02", response);` This one is executed 3 times?!

[image: output screenshot]

- The function I use to draw the table
  (there is just one function in code, but I'm confuse that some part of function execute 3 times, some part just one time )

```
create_certain_ipc_log_table();   // When the webpage is refreshed, the log table defaults to "server" mode.

// Listen for the change event of the dropdown select menu.
$("#exampleFormControlSelect1").change(function() {
    // Get the selected option element.
    var selectedOption = $(this).find(":selected");
    
    // Retrieve the value of "device_id" from the selected option element's dataset.
    var selectedDeviceId = selectedOption.data("device_id");
    
    console.log("Selected Device ID:", selectedDeviceId);
    selectedDeviceId = selectedOption.data("device_id").toString(); // Convert to string
    
    // Update the "device_id" property of the "sending_data_to_api_log_file_list" object.
    sending_data_to_api_log_file_list.device_id = selectedDeviceId;
    
    // Output the updated JSON object to the console to verify correct storage.
    console.log("Updated sending_data_to_api_log_file_list:", sending_data_to_api_log_file_list);

    var certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable()
    certain_ipc_log_table.destroy();
    $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").empty();
    
    // Call the function to create the "certain_ipc_log_table" using the updated "sending_data_to_api_log_file_list".
    create_certain_ipc_log_table(sending_data_to_api_log_file_list);
});
    

function create_certain_ipc_log_table(sending_data_to_api_log_file_list) {
    console.log("How many times does create_certain_ipc_log_table run?")
    
    let defaultOrder = 'desc'
    let defaultOrderColumn = 'id'

    // Use provided values as defaults if available.
    if (Order !== undefined) {
        defaultOrder = Order;
    }

    if (OrderColumn !== undefined) {
        defaultOrderColumn = OrderColumn;
    }

    defaultOrder = Order;
    defaultOrderColumn = OrderColumn;

    newValue = localStorage.getItem("newValue");
    var defaultData = {
        processing: true,
        lengthChange: true,
        serverSide: true,
        lengthMenu: [10,100],
        bDestroy: true,

        ajax: {
            url: newValue + '/api/log/files/list',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: function(d) { // Use 'data' instead of 'd'
                d.search = d.search.value; // Change d.search.value to data.search.value
                console.log(d);
                d.order_by = defaultOrder;
                d.order_column = defaultOrderColumn;
                console.log("d.order_by", d.order_by);
                console.log("d.order_column", d.order_column);
                return JSON.stringify(d);
            },
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + getToken,
            },
            dataSrc: function (response) {
                console.log("DATA for table 02", response);
                return response.data;
            }
        },

        columns: [
            { data: "filepath", title: "Filepath" },
            { data: "filename", title: "Filename" },
            { data: "extension", title: "Extension" },
            { data: "modified", title: "Modified" },
            { data: "size", title: "Size" },
            {
                data: null,
                title: accountType === "OP" ? "" : "ACTION",
                visible: accountType !== "OP",
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (accountType === "OP") {
                        return "";
                    } else {
                        return (
                            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-edit-delete" id="Edit_Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="" onclick="download_certain_ipc_log_to_txt(' + selectedDeviceId + ', \'' + row.filepath + '\', \'' + row.filename + '\')">Download</button>'
                        );
                    }
                },
            }
        ],

        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("xhr ERROR: ", xhr.responseText);
            console.log("status ERROR: ", status);
            console.log("error ERROR: ", error);
        }
    };

    var dataToUse = sending_data_to_api_log_file_list
        ? {
              ...defaultData,
              ajax: {
                  ...defaultData.ajax,
                  data: function(data) {
                      sending_data_to_api_log_file_list.search = data.search.value;
                      console.log("Data confirmation:", sending_data_to_api_log_file_list);
                      return JSON.stringify(sending_data_to_api_log_file_list);
                  },
              },
          }
        : defaultData;

    // Update the data of the "certain_ipc_log_table".
    var certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(dataToUse);

    // Draw the new table.
    certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(dataToUse);
    certain_ipc_log_table.draw();
}
```

how to deal with this? Aren't they both console.log in the same function

Comment: Is there a way you can make a [mcve]? What you show now is just a dump of your code

Comment: Someone else had this in 2018 https://github.com/digicorp/propeller/issues/73

Comment: ok, thanks for ur advice, I would make it shorter, and I read the link you provide, it might not that help, but thanks (ง๑ •̀_•́)ง

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the clue

Here the certain_ipc_log_table DataTable is initialized twice , and then the draw() method is called immediately~ which may lead to an infinite loop or excessive recursion.

```
    var certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(dataToUse);


    // certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(dataToUse);
    certain_ipc_log_table.draw();
```

one of the **Maximum call stack size exceeded** is fixed