# js encountered "Maximum call stack size exceeded" and wanted to find that infinite loop which cause this

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, datatables, webkit

Console output has  **Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Need to solve the problem of repeated loading (get out of the loop)

> I repaired one of the  "Maximum call stack size exceeded" a little earlier,by studying other discusstion
>
> is about initializing the certain_ipc_log_table DataTable twice in a row, and then calling the draw() method immediately~ May cause an infinite loop or excessive recursion

But there is still one "Maximum call stack size exceeded", I'm  stuck and need a hand

-error message

```
code.jquery.com_jquery-3.7.0.js:3871 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at access (code.jquery.com_jquery-3.7.0.js:3871:22)
    at jQuery.fn.init.attr (code.jquery.com_jquery-3.7.0.js:7862:10)
    at containsPmdClassPrefix (pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:181:15)
    at processNode (pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:149:8)
    at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:173:6
    at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:139:5
    at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:174:7
    at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:174:7
    at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:174:7
    at pro.propeller.in_docs_js_propeller-user-manual.js:174:7
```

Now I know the problem is here ( I delete this paragraph without reporting an error)
It may be repeated designation, initialize the same table, and trigger
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
     // Update the data of certain_ipc_log_table
      if (!certain_ipc_log_table) {
        certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(
          dataToUse
        );
      } else {
        certain_ipc_log_table.destroy();
        $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").empty();
        certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(
          dataToUse
        );
      }
```

But I have tried to change it to other methods, as follows, but it is still the same

```
       if (certain_ipc_log_table) {
         certain_ipc_log_table.clear().destroy();
         $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").empty();
         certain_ipc_log_table = null; // set the DataTable to null after destroying it
       }
      
       certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(dataToUse);
```

**How ​​to make these code better?**

---

- in case, here is the full code if someone want to take a look

I've condensed the content of the program and added some comments to aid understanding

(I add the `console.trace` )
[(screenshot) output of console.trace and error](https://imgur.com/a/SH8RenN)

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
  
  var rowData;
  var selectedDeviceId;

  console.trace("GET TOKEN", getToken);
  newValue = localStorage.getItem("newValue");
  
  var accountType = localStorage.getItem("acc_type");
  var certain_ipc_log_table ;

  let sending_data_to_api_log_file_list= {
      "draw": 1,
      "length": 10,
      "start": 0,
      "device_id": "",
      "search": "",
      "start_datetime": "",
      "end_datetime": ""
    }

    let df = {
      draw: 0,
      columns: ["device_id", "name", "group"],
    };
  
  
  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: newValue + '/api/ipc/select',
      async: true,
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "accept": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + getToken,
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(df),
      success: function (res) {
          
          console.trace('Successfully checked');
          console.trace("RES", res);
  
          var selectElement = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlSelect1");
  
          selectElement.innerHTML = "";
  
          var defaultOption = document.createElement("option");
          defaultOption.textContent = "Server";
          defaultOption.value = ''; // Set the value to an empty string
          defaultOption.dataset.device_id = ''; // Set the dataset.device_id to an empty string
          selectElement.appendChild(defaultOption);
  
          res.data.forEach(function (item) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
  
              // Set the text content of the option to a combination of group, device_id, and name
              option.textContent = item.group + " - " + item.device_id + " - " + item.name;
  
              // Store the individual values in data attributes for later use
              option.dataset.group = item.group;
              option.dataset.device_id = item.device_id;
              option.dataset.name = item.name;

              temp_device_id= item.device_id
              console.trace("item.device_id;",temp_device_id)
  
              selectElement.appendChild(option);
          });
      },
      error: function (error) {
          console.trace("ERROR", error);
      }
  });
  
  create_certain_ipc_log_table();   // Default log table is for the server when the web page is first loaded

  // Listen to the change event of the dropdown menu
  var selectChanged = false; // Add a flag to check if the dropdown menu has been changed

  // Listen to the change event of the dropdown menu
  
  $("#exampleFormControlSelect1").change(function() {
      // Get the selected option element
      var selectedOption = $(this).find(":selected");
      selectChanged = true; // Set the flag to true in the dropdown menu change event
  
      // Get the value of device_id from the selected option element's dataset
      selectedDeviceId = selectedOption.data("device_id");
  
      console.trace("Selected Device ID:", selectedDeviceId);
      selectedDeviceId = selectedOption.data("device_id").toString(); // Convert to string

  
      // Update the device_id property of the sending_data_to_api_log_file_list object
      sending_data_to_api_log_file_list.device_id = selectedDeviceId;
  
      // Output the updated JSON object to the console to check if it's stored correctly
      console.trace("Updated sending_data_to_api_log_file_list:", sending_data_to_api_log_file_list);

      certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable()
          certain_ipc_log_table.destroy();
  $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").empty();
  
      // Call the function to create certain_ipc_log_table with the updated sending_data_to_api_log_file_list
      if (selectChanged) {
          create_certain_ipc_log_table(sending_data_to_api_log_file_list);
          selectChanged = false; // Reset the flag to false
      }
  });
  
  function checkSelectChange() {
      if (selectChanged) {
          // Remove create_certain_ipc_log_table(sending_data_to_api_log_file_list);
          certain_ipc_log_table.destroy();
          $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").empty();
          certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(dataToUse);
          selectChanged = false; // Reset the flag to false
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(checkSelectChange);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(checkSelectChange); // Start checking
  
  function create_certain_ipc_log_table(sending_data_to_api_log_file_list) { 

    let defaultOrder = "desc";
    let defaultOrderColumn = "id";

      newValue = localStorage.getItem("newValue");
      var defaultData = {
          processing: true,
          lengthChange: true,
          serverSide: true,
          lengthMenu: [10,100],
          bDestroy: true,


          ajax: {
              url: newValue + '/api/log/files/list',
              type: "POST",
              contentType: 'application/json',
              data: function(d) { // Use 'data' instead of 'd'
                  d.search = d.search.value; // Change d.search.value to data.search.value
                  console.trace(d);
                  d.order_by = defaultOrder;
                  d.order_column = defaultOrderColumn;
                  console.trace("d.order_by", d.order_by);
                  console.trace("d.order_column", d.order_column);
                  return JSON.stringify(d);
              },
              headers: {
                  Authorization: "Bearer " + getToken,
              }
          },

          columns: [
              { data: "filepath", title: "filepath" },
              { data: "filename", title: "filename" },
              { data: "extension", title: "extension" },
              { data: "modified", title: "modified" },
              { data: "size", title: "size" },
              {
                  data: null,
                  title: accountType === "OP" ? "" : "ACTION",
                  visible: accountType !== "OP",
                  render: function (data, type, row) {
                      if (accountType === "OP") {
                          return "";
                      } else {
                          return (
                              '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-edit-delete" id="Edit_Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="" onclick="download_certain_ipc_log_to_txt(' + selectedDeviceId + ', \'' + row.filepath + '\', \'' + row.filename + '\')">Download</button>'

                          );
                      }
                  },
              }
          ],

          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.trace("xhr ERROR: ", xhr.responseText);
              console.trace("status ERROR: ", status);
              console.trace("error ERROR: ", error);
          }
      };

      var dataToUse = sending_data_to_api_log_file_list
          ? {
                ...defaultData,
                ajax: {
                    ...defaultData.ajax,
                    data: function(data) {
                        sending_data_to_api_log_file_list.search = data.search.value;
                        console.trace("Data confirmed", sending_data_to_api_log_file_list);
                        return JSON.stringify(sending_data_to_api_log_file_list);
                    },
                },
            }
          : defaultData;

          // Update the data of certain_ipc_log_table
          if (!certain_ipc_log_table) {
              certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(dataToUse);
          } else {

              certain_ipc_log_table.destroy();
              $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").empty();
              certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(dataToUse);
          }
  }

});
```

Comment: Include stack trace in the question please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [js face Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76881591/js-face-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Comment: nope, I did answer/ fix by myself once, but this time I need a hand,  I located the part of code where may cause **Maximum call stack size exceeded**, in `if (certain_ipc_log_table) {
         certain_ipc_log_table.clear().destroy();
         $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").empty();
         certain_ipc_log_table = null; // set the DataTable to null after destroying it
       }
      
       certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable(dataToUse);`

I correct the code several times , but fail, so  I need some advice

Comment: last time I fixed the problem myself, but this time I stock by different case. This is the reason I post the question

Comment: You should thoroughly analyse the stack trace, identifying each statement that is mentioned in it. Pasting pieces of code that we cannot run is not going to help much.

Comment: I adjust the code , put console.trace in and screenshot the output, pls take a look